# When selecting an item in a datra frame, I obtain the item and the Levels R

Tags: r

I have a data frame and when I select an item, I obtain next to the result, all the levels available in that column.

Is there a command to desactivate this? 
Or how should I call this element?

This is what I am doing at the moment:

```
a<-data$column[1]
```

and I obtain:

```
[1] 1
1256 Levels: 1 10 100 1000 ... 1000000
```

Comment: Do you mean to keep your variable as a `factor`, but suppress the printing of its levels in the console? Or do you not need your variable to be a `factor` at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `a` to be a number use:

```
a <- as.numeric(paste(data$column[1]))
a
[1] 1
```

If you want `a` to be a string use:

```
a <- as.character(data$column[1])
a
[1] "1"
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Try `x <- factor(5);as.numeric(x)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: `paste` is coercing to character while carrying out its other processes. Just coerce without the overhead `as.numeric(as.character(x))` or the more efficient but hard to remember `as.numeric(levels(x))[x]`